# Unable to install mclust package in rstudio

Tags: r, linux

I am having an issue when installing the "mclust" package on rstudio.

Here is the warning message:

```
>install.packages("mclust")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/mclust_5.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2535477 bytes (2.4 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.4 MB

* installing *source* package ‘mclust’ ...
** package ‘mclust’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

/home/usr/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc -
I/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 
-I/home/usr/anaconda3/include   -fpic  -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -
ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -
I/home/usr/anaconda3/include  -c init.c -o init.o

make: /home/usr/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc: Command 
not found

/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:160: recipe for target 'init.o' 
failed

make: *** [init.o] Error 127

ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mclust’
* removing ‘/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/R/library/mclust’

Warning in install.packages :
 installation of package ‘mclust’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
  ‘/tmp/RtmpGCCIZS/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

In addition, I also tried to access the directory /home.usr/anaconda3/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc ,which apparently doesn't exist.

Comment: Please edit by correctly aligning your error messages and file directory.

Comment: @Daniel I made some changes, just how it appeared.